# How to fix a URL colon error that changes colon to %3a

Tags: swift, url

I have a URL as below

> components.host = "37.143.66.25:9875"

This URL contains a colon `:`, but when I try to make a request I get this error message

> NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://37.143.66.25%3a9875/spots/test, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://37.143.66.25%3a9875/spots/test, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}

And in this error message, colon `:` is displayed as `%3a`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add host and port separately, like (assuming `components` is `URLComponents`)

```
components.host = "37.143.66.25"
components.port = 9875
```

otherwise it thinks that your port is part of host name

Comment: :) copy-paste issue... yes, from the provided code I assumed that `components` is-a URLComponents